# display /admin/builds/blocks in several page drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

how to moderate for /admin/builds/blocks because i have 150 blocks and this loaded page is very slow , can i this page show in several page? or show any region blocks display in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use [Views Hacks](http://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module which would let you create a custom view of the blocks.
2. You could use the increasingly popular [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module which would allow you to do *some* configuration without needing the /admin/build/blocks
3. You could try out this [experimental module](http://drupal.org/project/blockadminlight).